# ITMS-90378 "CFBundleIdentifier Collision" WatchKit

Tags: ios, watchkit, cfbundleidentifier

ERROR ITMS-90378 "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.appname.watchkit' under the iOS application 'appname.app'"

i have added **five** bundle identifier to app
one in main ios app in info.plist, two in watchkit app in info.plist,two in watchkit extension app in info.plist

i found above error when submitting app to appstore.

can anybody help me out?

thanks in advance